# accidentally created a symbolic link

Tags: apache, centos, symlink

I accidentally created a symbolic link of `sites-available` inside `sites-enabled`. Now, I don't know what happened but I did a `rm -rf sites-available` to delete the symbolic link, but that is not what happened. Instead, all my configuration files inside `sites-available` was deleted. The worst is the symbolick link of `sites-available` is still inside the `sites-enabled`. I tried `rm -f sites-available` but it won't delete it. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Did you create a hardlink or a softlink? In anycase if the handle is treated like a directory you would need rmdir not rm.

Comment: I created a softlink, doing a `rmdir sites-available` would result in `rmdir: failed to remove \'sites-available/': Not a directory`

Comment: What does ls -la sites-available tell you?

Comment: A softlink is always removable by rm unless your filesystem has been remounted as read-only.

Comment: Doing `ls -la sites-available` will display the contents of actual `sites-available` directory including the . & ..

Comment: @BjoernRennhak - I agree, I can remove other softlink by doing `rm` what confuses me is this `sites-available`, it just can't be deleted.

Comment: Sorry, try ls -la | egrep -i sites and tell me what the permissions are exactly on the link in question

Comment: @BjoernRennhak - I got this `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19 May 22 13:13 sites-available -> ../sites-available/`

Comment: Hm, shows us that is a simple normal symlink. When you type "mount" is the partition you are working on "r" or "rw" ?

Comment: Yeah its a normal symlink. Checked mount it is on `rw`

Comment: Ok, this makes no sense. Symlinks are normal deletable, is that really not a mounted device via e.g. mount --bind ? Possibly also you have not the right permissions to delete?

Comment: Im not sure regarding the `mount --bind` and it is a dedicated server, but I am using the `root` account so possibly I have permissions to delete.

Comment: Backup the entire apache folder, rm -rf it and re-install. If that doesn't work, nothing will.

Comment: Tried to repro and came to conclusion that contrary what the OP describes, they most probably really did `rm -rf sites-available/` (nb the **trailing slash**), not  the reported `rm -rf sites-available` (without slash). Appending the slash to folder symlink makes `rm` really wipe the target's folder content, instead of only removing the symlink itself. I was unable to repro any destructive outcome without the slash. (Btw, not sure why OP included "force + recursive" flags when they intended to remove single symlink, but it does not make a difference here. Muscle memory perhaps.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed directory to sites-enabled, if you want to remove symlink then change directory to correct path:

> cd path/sites-enabled

and then remove sites-available, but first make sure no longer you need it.

> rm -vf sites-available

Answer (score 0):

Note the difference between

```
rm -rf symboliclink
```

and

```
rm -rf symboliclink/
```